# I am trying to build a program on linux

Tags: linux, makefile, geoip

So I am trying to build this https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-c I have git cloned it and I followed the instructions but on the frist step it says to run ./configure, I can not find configure though. I have tried the configure.am but i get this error.

```
root@------:/usr/share/nginx/www/Geo/geoip-api-c# ./configure.ac 
./configure.ac: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./configure.ac: line 1: `dnl AM_CONFIG_HEADER(config.h)'
```

What am I missing?

One last question, what are the different make files extension/formats for? like .VC .in .am

EDIT:

I ran that file and just got this error back:

```
root@------:/usr/share/nginx/www/Geo/geoip-api-c# ./bootstrap 
rm: cannot remove `ltmain.sh': No such file or directory
./bootstrap: 5: ./bootstrap: autoreconf: not found
root@------:/usr/share/nginx/www/Geo/geoip-api-c# ^C
root@------:/usr/share/nginx/www/Geo/geoip-api-c#
```

Comment: probably the file format is in `DOS` try converting to unix format using `dos2unix` and try again

Comment: I downloaded the package and when I executed ./boostrap the configure script showed up, but it is showing me other errors aswell.

Comment: `configure.ac` is intended to be an input for `autoconf`, it's not meant to be *executed*.  You execute the generated `configure` instead.

Comment: -1 for not reading the README installation instructions first.  The `autoreconf` script comes from autoconf, so you need to install autoconf.

Answer (score 2):

The section "Installation" in the `README.md` explains how to build the software. You are missing this important step:

> If you are using a GitHub checkout, please run the `bootstrap` script first to set up the build environment.